# How to find resultant for 2D vectors?

Tags: vectors

[image]

Here , in 1st image. We have A = 3i and B=4j.

R for A and $B = 3i+4j$ which can be found out by (Methods that I know ):

1. Addition of A & B
2. By triangle law I.e joining tail of 3i to head of 4j.

In image 2 , we have a 2D vector.

It is a little different from steps in image 1. First , I we find the resultant for A and B  vector.

Then , Resultant can be found out by :

1. Addition I.e $(3i+4i),(2j-3j) = 7i,-1j$ .

2)Triangle law :We need to join is the resultant of A and B vector to find total resultant of A and B vector. But it’s not the same. Both Resultant A and B have only their tail here.  If I shift the vector resultant of A vector towards the head of B’s resultant. We can find out the total resultant but the coordinates of the final resultant come out to be different.

We get is $ ( -7i , -1j)$.

Therefore , I thought we could use parallelogram law here. But I’m not able to understand on how to use it. I will have to first add up the vector like the 1st case.

So , please share your method on how should we
join these two vectors so that we are able to solve it like the 1st image I.e using triangle law.

If you have any other method , then do share it.

Comment: You made a mistake on the first sum: it’s $7i-j$ at the end

Comment: If $a=3i+2j,b=4i-3j$, their sum is exactly $7i-j$ and that holds no matter which way you visually add them.

Comment: It seems you haven't joined the tails properly, if you are getting $-7i,-1j$. The i part is going wrong, so we will have to see why it is going wrong.